# android apk built with Unreal intstall on emulator fails - INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: android, unreal-engine4

From unreal I built Android Multi apk. With drag and drop it fails to install on x86 emulator and with the command file on unreal build directory it fails as well with following error:

```
C:\Users\_\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject\Builds\Android\Android_Multi>C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe  uninstall io.Github.BigbangKing.Test
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Installing existing application. Failures here indicate a problem with the device (connection or storage permissions) and are fatal.

C:\Users\_\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject\Builds\Android\Android_Multi>C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe  install MyProject-armv7.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install MyProject-armv7.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

There was an error installing the game or the obb file. Look above for more info.
```

Unreal Engine generated amrv7 apk. How can I build apk compatible for x86 emulator and newer arm processors?

note: It installs and works on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your project in Unreal Engine Editor
2. Edit -> Project Setting
3. Scroll to Platforms -> Android
4. Scroll to Build -> Check Support x86_64
   It requires Github source. Good luck !